# Chart in C# is displaying duplicate values

Tags: c#, charts

I am writing code to display date-bills pair graph on chart with date on x-axis and bills on y-axis. But it is displaying 2 bars for each entry.

```
 this.chart1.Series["G.R"].Points.AddXY("25/07/2015", 35);
```

the output for this line is 2 bars with same values. 
I dont want them to get repeated. How to achieve this goal??

Comment: Where is the code for `AddXY` ? This kind of information is needed.

Comment: this is the only line of code as it contains AddXY in it

Comment: Where is the `Points` type class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line of code by itself does NOT produce 2 bars:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series["G.R"].Points.AddXY("25/07/2015", 35);
}
```

[image]

So, there must be some other line of code somewhere else. Or you may have multiple series in the same chart.